# How to use .not() to hide all divs except the one which was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to enlarge a set of images which have thumbnails inside divs.

When I click the `.thumbnail` class, which is applied to the images, the image enlarges but I would like all the other products to disappear.

I tried adding a class with display: none but because the image being passed to the function is inside the div it's still not being shown (I think that's why) so I've tried using opacity but without success. I will add the relevant code below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');


  images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.addEventListener('click', enlarge);
  });

  function enlarge(e) {
    var image = e.target,
      interval,
      height = 200,
      width = 200,
      z = $(this).css("z-index"); //Obtain the current z-index of the image which has been clicked
    /*thisProduct = */

    $(this).css("z-index", z + 10); //increase the z-index of just the image which has been selected by 10
    $('#product-container').addClass('disable-click'); //Stops other products from being enlarged whilst another is
    $('.unhidden').not($(this)).addClass('noOpacity');

  }

});
```

```css
.noOpacity {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product-container">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/home-bg.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Mexican Nachos - £6.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/enchilada.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Enchiladas - £10.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/quesadilla.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Quesadilla - £10.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/shrimp.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Shrimp Stir Fry - £10.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/tacos.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Tacos - £5.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/tortilla.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Tortillas - £7.99
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Product container -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have attached event handlers with `.thumbnail` elements not with `.unhidden`, So you need target parent element using `.closest()`/`.parents()` then `not()` can be used. So use

```
$('.unhidden').not($(this).closest('.unhidden')).addClass('noOpacity');
```

instead of

```
$('.unhidden').not($(this)).addClass('noOpacity');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');


  images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.addEventListener('click', enlarge);
  });

  function enlarge(e) {
    var image = e.target,
      interval,
      height = 200,
      width = 200,
      z = $(this).css("z-index"); //Obtain the current z-index of the image which has been clicked
    /*thisProduct = */

    $(this).css("z-index", z + 10); //increase the z-index of just the image which has been selected by 10
    $('#product-container').addClass('disable-click'); //Stops other products from being enlarged whilst another is
    $('.unhidden').not($(this).closest('.unhidden')).addClass('noOpacity');

  }

});
```

```css
.noOpacity {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product-container">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/home-bg.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Mexican Nachos - £6.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/enchilada.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Enchiladas - £10.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/quesadilla.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Quesadilla - £10.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/shrimp.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Shrimp Stir Fry - £10.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/tacos.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Tacos - £5.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/tortilla.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Tortillas - £7.99
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Product container -->
```

Comment: God bless you Sir. Thank you @Satpal it's working now

Answer (score 2):

Why do you mix `jQuery` with pure js? Let's do it with only `jQuery`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
    var image = e.target,
      interval,
      height = 200,
      width = 200,
      z = $(this).css("z-index");
    $(this).css("z-index", z + 10);
    $('#product-container').addClass('disable-click');
    $('.unhidden').not($(this).parent().parent()).addClass('noOpacity');
  });
});
```

```css
.unhidden {}

.noOpacity {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product-container">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/home-bg.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Mexican Nachos - £6.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/enchilada.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Enchiladas - £10.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/quesadilla.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Quesadilla - £10.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/shrimp.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Shrimp Stir Fry - £10.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/tacos.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Tacos - £5.99
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="product" class="unhidden">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="assets/tortilla.jpg" class="thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        Tortillas - £7.99
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Product container -->
```

Comment: Thank you @Kind user although I already accepted an answer I used the .parent() stuff to aid me with somethign else +1

Comment: @EthanBristow It's all good, hovewer using just jQuery makes code looks lighter (:

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click', function(){
    $('.image-container').not(this).closest('.image-container').hide();
})
```

On clicking any thumbnail class, all thumbnail classes ( except for 'this') will get hidden.

Comment: That removes the other images which is nice but not their containers. In my application the images are inside a div which has a border and some text as well, I would like all of that to display: none

Comment: I've used this type of code before and tested it and it worked. Did I copy his code no

Comment: I thought you wanted the images, sorry, just put in the container then

Comment: Yes but becuase the (this) element is inside the container which i'm hiding it gets hidden to, or at least I think, but I've tried it and everything dissapears including the desired image

Comment: This in this context is the image not the container. This won't work

Comment: Now I feel like you are just guessing. Still a no.

Comment: your .not(this) is the wrong this your this will always reference a .thumbnail which will never be a .image-container

Answer (score 0):

Use classes and IDs to construct your functionality.
For example:

```
<div class='thumbnail'>A</div>
<div class='thumbnail'>B</div>
<div class='thumbnail' id='1'>C</div>
```

Try this function:

```
function showOne(id) {
    $('.thumbnail').not('#' + id).hide();
}

showOne(1);​
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using .not($(this)) the this you are referencing is the imagine not the div with '.unihdden' on it. try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');


    images.forEach(function(image) {
        image.addEventListener('click', enlarge);
    });
  });
function enlarge(e) {
    var image = e.target,
        interval,
        height = 200,
        width = 200,
        z = $(this).css("z-index"); //Obtain the current z-index of the image which has been clicked
        /*thisProduct = */

    $(this).css("z-index", z + 10);  //increase the z-index of just the image which has been selected by 10
    $('#product-container').addClass('disable-click'); //Stops other products from being enlarged whilst another is
    $('.unhidden').not($(this).closest('.unhidden')).addClass('noOpacity');
    /*$('.unhidden').addClass("hide");*/

}
```